# Bayesian NMA with gemtc R package: How can I transform the output of the relatife.effect.table (log Hazard Ratio) to Hazard ratios?

Tags: r, bayesian-networks

I have just make a Bayesan NMA with gemtc R package and obtained the matrix (relative.effect.table), but the data in it is in a format that I have to convert (log Hazard Ratio). I was wondering if there is a package or function that can convert the data automatically or if I have to do it by one by one.

Thank you and I hope you can help me out.

I searched if there was a package or function to convert them automatically but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.